# Laravel MQTT subscription - Undefined index: qos

Tags: mqtt, laravel-8, phpmqtt

I try to subscribe to a topic, I get below mentioned error:

**Undefined array key "qos"**

**My code:**

`try {

```
$mqtt = new Mqtt();
$mqtt->ConnectAndSubscribe('myTopic', function ($topic, $msg) {
       Log::info("Mqtt Msg Received");
});
```

} catch (\Exception $e) {

```
 dd($e->getMessage());
```

}`

(As in the example, I inserted it into a controller).

*$buffer .= chr($callback["qos"]);*

in vendor/salmanzafar/laravel-mqtt/src/MqttClass/MqttService.php:173

If I solve the problem adding a simple "?? 0", when I try to subscribe, it doesn't seems to work.

I'm using Laravel 8.16 with PHP 8.0 and "salmanzafar/laravel-mqtt": "^2.0".

Answer (score 0):

Docs: https://packagist.org/packages/salmanzafar/laravel-mqtt

Please check whether QoS is configured in your `Config/mqtt.php`:

```
    'host'      => env('mqtt_host','127.0.0.1'),
    'password'  => env('mqtt_password',''),
    'username'  => env('mqtt_username',''),
    'certfile'  => env('mqtt_cert_file',''),
    'localcert' => env('mqtt_local_cert', ''),
    'localpk'   => env('mqtt_local_pk', ''),
    'port'      => env('mqtt_port','1883'),
    'debug'     => env('mqtt_debug',false) //Optional Parameter to enable debugging set it to True
    'qos'       => env('mqtt_qos', 0), // set quality of service here
    'retain'    => env('mqtt_retain', 0) // it should be 0 or 1 Whether the message should be retained.- Retain Flag
```

Comment: Yes. It's configured.